# Any free TCP socket monitoring application?

Tags: windows, monitoring, tcpip

Please can you suggest any free application by which I can monitor the opening/open/closing TCP/IP sockets? Something that can tell me:

1. Total number of sockets currently (different count for different socket states)
2. Max till launch
3. Any graph of socket usage (such as network or CPU graph shown in Windows Task Manager utility)

Can you think of any such application?

EDIT: Sorry about not giving enough details. Any application that can work on Windows OS would be welcomed.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and add some more details: mainly which OS you'd like the utility to run on. As the question stands, it's very difficult to answer.

Comment: What kind of graph? Number of open (active) connections, average octets sent per connection? Or one of many other possibilities...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Windows,
[**TCPView**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) from [**SysinternalsSuite**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) will give you currently open and listening sockets.
It will also allow taking snapshots to text files for further analysis.

In general,
The **netstat** command will also help (from cmd.exe on windows, shell on unixes)

```
netstat -an
```

Answer (score 3):

try wireshark. It is actually a network protocol analyzer. It can monitor and report tcp traffic.

Answer (score 2):

aports, tcpview, netstat